# Alignment in siunitx table using number of decimal places stored in a command

Tags: tables, siunitx

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\def\accuracy{2}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format = 1]
    S[table-format = 1.\accuracy]
    S[table-format = 2.\accuracy]
  }
   \toprule
      {Time, $x$}
    & {Erosion per year, $g(x)$}
    & {Erosion in total, $h(x)$} \\[0.75ex]
      {Year}
    & {\unit{\m}}
    & {\unit{\m}} \\
   \midrule
     1 & 2.25 &  2.25 \\
     2 & 3.14 &  5.39 \\
     3 & 4.98 & 10.37 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

When I use the value defined in `\accuracy` as an indicator of the number of decimal places in the alignment in columns two and three, the alignment is equivalent to 1 decimal place instead of 2. What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

When I replace `\accuracy` by `2` in the `S`-column format, everything is fine.

P.S. I use the same number of decimal places elsewhere; that's why I've stored the value in `\accuracy`.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't do `\def\accuracy`, better would be `\newcommand*\accuracy{2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I don't think this was an out-and-out bug, it's clearly not ideal: in other places, table cells are expanded before checking for digits. As such, I will adjust `table-format` to sort this. For the present, you can add

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\keys_define:nn { siunitx }
  {
    table-format .code:n =
      {
        \group_begin:
          \protected@edef \l__siunitx_table_tmp_tl {#1}
        \exp_args:NNV \group_end:
        \__siunitx_table_split:nNNN \l__siunitx_table_tmp_tl
          \l__siunitx_table_before_model_tl
          \l__siunitx_table_model_tl
          \l__siunitx_table_after_model_tl
        \exp_args:NV \__siunitx_table_generate_model:n \l__siunitx_table_model_tl
        \tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_table_align_mode_tl { format }
      }
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

to your source.

**Update**

The code has been added to the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package as of version 3.0.14; see https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.895.1624080471.2581.ctan-ann@ctan.org.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is expansion. [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) doesn't fully expand the value of `table-format` while parsing it. You can expand it before passing it on to `siunitx` and then everything works fine (you have to watch out, protect anything that shouldn't be expanded before the table reads its preamble by either `\noexpand` or `\unexpanded{<things>}` inside the argument of `\expanded`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\def\accuracy{2}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \expanded{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format = 1]
    S[table-format = 1.\accuracy]
    S[table-format = 2.\accuracy]
  }}
   \toprule
      {Time, $x$}
    & {Erosion per year, $g(x)$}
    & {Erosion in total, $h(x)$} \\[0.75ex]
      {Year}
    & {\unit{\m}}
    & {\unit{\m}} \\
   \midrule
     1 & 2.25 &  2.25 \\
     2 & 3.14 &  5.39 \\
     3 & 4.98 & 10.37 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]